# Comparing a list of lists with a list to find similar numbers

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, nested

Here is what I tried:

```
my_tickets = [ [ 7, 17, 37, 19, 23, 43],
           [ 7, 2, 13, 41, 31, 43],
           [ 2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17],
           [13, 17, 37, 19, 23, 43] ]

def lotto_matches(xs, my_tickets):
   xi = 0 # could be used to pick specific things from lists
   yi = 0 # could be used to pick specific things from lists
   result = []
   for i in my_tickets: # List of lists
      for x in xs: # Picks
         if my_tickets[i] == xs[x]: #Not sure what my if statement is suppose to be
            result.append() # I don't know what goes in the parenthesis
    print (result)
    return (result)

lotto_matches([42,4,7,11,1,13], my_tickets)
```

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of tickets and a draw, and returns a list telling how many picks were correct on each ticket.

It is supposed to return `[1,2,3,1]` but my output is completely wrong.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The overhead of creating sets is hardly worthwhile unless your lottery draw has a lot more balls.

```
def lotto_matches(xs, my_tickets):
    xs = set(xs) # optional - may not be any faster if xs is a small list
    return [sum(x in xs for x in t) for t in my_tickets]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `intersection` like this:

```
def lotto_matches(pick, my_tickets):
    result = map(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(pick)), my_tickets)
    return result

print lotto_matches([42,4,7,11,1,13], my_tickets)
```

where `pick` is your ticket to match.

If you are using Python 3, `map` returns iterator which is probably not what you want, so you'll need to

```
return list(result)
```

Comment: in your function. that's the replacement for the whole body of your function.

Comment: it never uses my first parameter xs. when I run the program, I get nothing. Is it suppose to look like this?                          def lotto_matches(xs, my_tickets):
    pick = [7,21,22,26,34,43]
    map(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(pick)), my_tickets)
lotto_matches([42,4,7,11,1,13], my_tickets)

Comment: @pakiboii Mate, I simply renamed it to `pick` because you should really use meaningful names for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one liner:

```
output = [len(list(set(a_list) & set(draw))) for a_list in my_tickets]
```

Comment: draw = [42,4,7,11,1,13]

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not accumulating results properly in your code. Each iteration you should start counting over and at the end append the result.
2. `for i in my_tickets` iterates over tickets themselves, not their indices.

Here is the fixed code:

```
def lotto_matches(xs, my_tickets):
    results = []
    for ticket in my_tickets:
        result = 0
        for number in ticket:
            for x in xs: 
                if number == x: 
                    result += 1
        results.append(result)
    return result
```

---

Now, this can be made prettier by flattening your loops:

1. This if statement

   ```
   if number == x: 
       result += 1
   ```

   can use the fact that `True` is interpreted as 1:

   ```
   result += (number==x)
   ```
2. This

   ```
   result = 0
   for number in ticket:
       for x in xs: 
           result += (number==x)
   ```

   is a sum calculated using a nested loop, which can be converted to this

   ```
   result = sum(number==x for number in ticket for x in xs)
   ```

   This is checking for all `x` values which are present in the `ticket`, which can be simplified using `in` (same thing, `x in ticket` will return `True` (1) when `x` is present in `ticket`):

   ```
   result = sum(x in ticket for x in xs)
   ```

   That is, if `x` from `xs` is present in `ticket`, we want to add one to our sum.
3. Now, we have this

   ```
   results = []
   for ticket in my_tickets:
       result = sum(x in ticket for x in xs)
       results.append(result)
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   results = [sum(x in ticket for x in xs) for ticket in my_tickets]
   ```
4. So, your whole code can be a one-liner:

   ```
   def lotto_matches(xs, my_tickets):
       return [sum(x in ticket for x in xs) for ticket in my_tickets]
   ```